# what's wrong with my onDestroy? (old api camera)

Tags: android-camera, ondestroy

I've been writing a flashlight app as my very first app to learn the fundamentals, and although everything is working out fine, the flash doesn't work when I close the app (until I reboot or open some other camera app).

Is anything wrong with my onDestroy?

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(camera != null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;}}
```

I'm using the old camera API as my only available device runs on API 21. Looking at the package documentation suggests I'm doing everything ok. The flash behaves normally, but as soon as I pause the activity or close the app the flash becomes unavailable, even though I thought I was releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, missed the same code in onPause() and onStop().

Works flawlessly now.